# Error with dates in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to run a statement on sqlite database from android...I wish to return some records from a table which lastChagedDate bigger than the date I give.

Let's say I have this:

```
private String ending_date = "2012-01-01 08:24:59";

roadmapSyncStmt = "SELECT * FROM roadmap WHERE lastChangedDate > '"+ ending_date +"'";
```

The roadmapSyncStmt is the one I will execute on sqlite table full of dates.
The statement will look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM roadmap WHERE lastChangedDate >"2012-01-01 08:24:59"
```

And when I run I get this error:

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "2012": syntax error

and no data in cursor even though my database contains plenty of data which respects this condition. Does someone know what I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure if you can compare dates with a greater than condition

Comment: I don't know....I will find out tonight!

Comment: is `lastChangedDate ` of `date` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose your date value in single quotes, not double quotes.  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM roadmap WHERE lastChangedDate > '2012-01-01 08:24:59'
```

Whilst you are learning, I recommend that you install a PC base SQLite editor, for example "SQLite Database Browser" which you can find on SourceForge.   It's much quicker and easier than testing in your app.  I would go so far as to say that all of the DB development, testing, query creation etc should be done on your PC then it's pretty much a copy/paste exercise to get it into your app.

Good luck.